# Pre checking h:manyCheckbox after selecting value from h:selectOneMenu in JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2, checkbox, drop-down-menu, valuechangelistener

I want to precheck multiple checkboxes after selecting a value from dropdown box and calling a valueChangeListener on dropdown box. Following is the code:

In JSF page:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="roleName" styleClass="text" value="#{role.roleID}" valueChangeListener="#{role.processValueChange}" immediate="true" onchange="submit()">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Select--" itemValue="--Select--"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItems noSelectionValue="--Select--" value="#{role.rolesVoList}" var="x" itemLabel="#{x.roleName}" itemValue="#{x.roleID}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<p>
    <h:outputText value="Notifications" styleClass="label" />
</p>
<p>
    <h:selectManyCheckbox id="notificationPrivileges" value="#{role.notificationPrivileges}" layout="pageDirection">
        <f:selectItems value="#{role.notificationPrivilegeMap}" />
    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
</p>
```

In Managed Bean:

```
private List<RolesVo> rolesVoList;
    private boolean checkBoxSet = false;
    private List<Integer> notificationPrivileges;
    private Map<String, Integer> notificationPrivilegeMap;
    private RolePrivilegeVo rolePrivilege;

    public void processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        messageHandler = new MessageHandler();
        int newValue = (Integer) event.getNewValue();
        setRoleID(newValue);
        try {
            rolePrivilege = roleService.getRolePrivileges(newValue);
            setNotificationPrivileges(rolePrivilege.getPrivilegeIDs());
            setCheckBoxSet(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            messageHandler.addGlobalErrorMessage(OATSConstants.errorFetchPrivilege);
        }

    }
```

getPrivilegeIDs() returns a list of integers. Form is being submitted and valueChangeListener method is being processed successfully but the checkboxes are not being selected after that. Please point me what i am doing wrong. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Your code is hard to understand. The properties referenced in the view doesn't match the properties referenced in the model. It seems that your getters/setters have different method names than the property names. Please pay a bit more attention to this kind of inconsitenties in your future questions.

Comment: Oops, sorry i pasted the wrong variable. I have edited it. Sorry for not pasting complete code as it clutters the question. roleVoList is Map<String, Integer> for the labels and value of roles, roleID is an integer. Also i have tried using <f:ajax> but i am getting the same result and the checkboxes are not selected.

Comment: Have you used the converter as explained in my answer?

Comment: Nope, haven't used it. I will try using it, right now i am not in office and don't have access to repository. I will let you know definitely whether it worked. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @BalusC I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. Here are the links to managed bean and view respectively. Please point out what am i doing wrong


http://pastebin.com/4PyDk0zR

http://pastebin.com/tYJh2CfQ

Answer (score 0):

It fails because you didn't explicitly specify a converter for the `<h:selectManyCheckbox>`. You're using generified collections like `List` and `Map`. EL does not have any support for generics and interprets everything as `String` by default. This will fail on `equals()` tests to check if the item has to be checked or not.

As you're using `Integer`, you need to specify the `javax.faces.Integer` converter:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox ... converter="javax.faces.Integer">
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you're using the old JSF 1.x hack of abusing the `valueChangeListener` with `immediate="true"` and `onchange="submit()` in order to populate another component. This is pretty clumsy and may fail whenever you're using validation anywhere in the same form. Rather use the new JSF 2.0 provided `<f:ajax>` tag. It will then look like follows:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="roleName" styleClass="text" value="#{role.roleID}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Select--" itemValue="--Select--"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItems noSelectionValue="--Select--" value="#{role.rolesVoList}" var="x" itemLabel="#{x.roleName}" itemValue="#{x.roleID}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{role.processValueChange}" render="rolePrivileges" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<p>
    <h:outputText value="Role Management" styleClass="label" />
</p>
<p>
    <h:selectManyCheckbox id="rolePrivileges" value="#{role.rolePrivileges}" layout="pageDirection" converter="javax.faces.Integer">
        <f:selectItems value="#{role.rolePrivilegeMap}" />
    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
</p>
```

with

```
public void processValueChange(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    // ...
}
```